# Function to find minimum element in array

Tags: functions

i have this code:

```
Minimum[numbers_] :=
 {
  minimum = numbers[[1]];
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[numbers], i++,
    If[minimum > numbers[[i]],
     minimum = numbers[[i]],
     minimum = minimum;
     ]
    ]
   Return[minimum];
  }

Minimum[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}]
```

Why i always get a NULL value from this function?(Out[] = {Null})

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: The semicolon represents `CompoundExpression` and suppresses the output if it is not followed by another command, because it then assumes that the "other command" is `None`.

Comment: the curly brackets `{}` wrapping your "function" code are a basic error (unless you intend to output a one element  list..). Make those `()` and terminate  the `For` with a semicolon and this works (not pretty but it works.. )

Comment: Incidentally:  `Fold[If[# < #2, ##] &, {4, 8, 1, 5, 3, 9, 5}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the built-in `Min` function, maybe this?

```
 Minimum[numbers_] := Block[{minimum = numbers[[1]]},
        For[i = 1, i <= Length[numbers], i++, 
             If[minimum > numbers[[i]], minimum = numbers[[i]], 
             minimum = minimum;
               ]
          ];
        minimum]
```

But if you really want your function, this works fine:

```
  Minimum[numbers_] := {minimum = numbers[[1]];
     For[i = 1, i <= Length[numbers], i++, 
      If[minimum > numbers[[i]], minimum = numbers[[i]], 
      minimum = minimum;]]; minimum}
```